# Comparison of two binary images opencv python

Tags: python, image, opencv, binary, comparison

I need to compare two binary images.  I currently just calculate the number of black pixels on the image and if it is close to template values or a bit more than it means they are similar. Otherwise, they are not the same.

This is the code as I find the numbers of black pixels on the image.

```
#Get all non-black pixels 
count = cv2.countNonZero(thresh_temp)
# get pixel count of image
height, width= thresh_temp.shape
cntPixels = height*width
# compute all black pixels
 cntBlack = cntPixels - count
print('This is only black pixels',cntBlack)
```

Comment: What sort of problems are you encountering?

Comment: you should XOR the images and count the number of pixels that are different between the images.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: hello! My question which metric to use. How to compare them and be 100% sure that they are different or pretty similar. Let's say I have one binary image with one important detail in the middle (similar to the template) and have another one without this middle part.